# What's wrong with my Android Manifest?

Tags: java, android, xml

My manifest keeps saying, `"The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed."` I thought it happened when I tried to create a new activity but I am not sure. Below is my code, with the package name blocked out only.

```
<<<<<<< Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.000000"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.000000" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.0000000" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignInActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_in"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.0000000" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.0000000" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your manifest seems ok, but as much as possible do not try to use digits as package / project name better if you have com.example.abcdefg rather than com.example.00000. I think that's the problem also put your target sdk to 21.

Comment: Delete this: <<<<<<< Original. This line seems a garbage from Git merge.

Comment: I put the 0's because I didn't want people to know the name of my app haha. It isn't in the actual manifest. It is example.xxxxxx if that is a better example haha sorry! Also, shouldn't I only put it to 21 if I plan it being on Android Wear? Will do it anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Mike Thank you! That was it! I knew that wasn't there before haha. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
<<<<<<< Original
```

Looks like a bad git conflict resolution.